# Get AccountName / UPN in a UWP App when logged on in Azure

Tags: azure, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am creating a UWP app which shows certain data, depending on the logged on user.
The user is logged on in Windows Azure and the computer account is also joined to Azure.
I have enabled the "Account Information" feature in the app manifest.

I am trying to find out the user data, using the User Class, like mentioned in several examples online:

```
        private async void GetAllUserData()
    {

        var users = await User.FindAllAsync();

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var authenticationStatus = user.AuthenticationStatus;
            var nonRoamableId = user.NonRoamableId;
            var provider = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.ProviderName);
            var accountName = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
            var displayName = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DisplayName);
            var domainName = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);
            var principalName = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.PrincipalName);
            var firstName = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.FirstName);
            var guestHost = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.GuestHost);
            var lastName = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.LastName);
            var sessionInitiationProtocolUri = await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.SessionInitiationProtocolUri);
            var userType = user.Type;
        }
    }
```

The only properties I can get from the user object are:

- DisplayName
- AuthenticationStatus
- NonRoamableId
- UserType

All other properties remain empty. From my understanding, when I am logged in to Windows Azure, at least the principal name should have a value.

What am I doing wrong - or in other words - what do I have to do, to get account information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling "Enterprise Authentication" feature in my app manifest, the UPN is filled in the principalName variable.

I know, this does not the real authentication job for the application, but for my purpose it is sufficient to have the UPN, authenticated in Windows.

For more information about adding Azure authentication to an app I have found the following links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2/